# make view accessible to only specific users (i.e. who created that model) in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have one model which has user as its ForeignKey attribute which is auto fill ie. logged in user is filled there. I have made token authentication. Only Authenticated // i mean authorized users can visit that view. But i am planning to make such that ***only the user which had created that model object can only update the content of that object.*** 
For example:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    sth_name = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    sth_qty = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

on my View:
I override perform_create() to associate to above model automaticall.

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
     return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

What do i exactly need to do? I have to write some permissions method, But I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an object level permission. The DRF tutorial covers this nicely here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions

Specifically, create a file `permissions.py` in your app, and add this permission there:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Then, in your view class which has the update resource for the `Something` model (probably `SomethingDetail`), add the `permission_classes` field:

```
class SomethingDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Something.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user when retrieving the object

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Something, pk=pk, user=request.user)
```

Note that this will throw 404. If you want 403 error, use custom condition to check the user and raise `PermissionDenied`. If you want to do this for multiple views, put the condition logic in a decorator.